# Error on rebuilding the project after updating syncfusion nuget

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget, syncfusion

Currently I am using
Xamarin forms 3.6.0.539721
Syncfusion nuget Version 17.1.0.53

now i am trying to update syncfusion nuget version to 18.2.0.44
Steps:

1. Installed Syncfusion Licensing from 17.1.0.53 to 18.2.0.44
2. then I install syncfusion.xamarin.core from 17.1.0.53 to 18.2.0.44
3. then I install syncfusion.xamarin.sfnumericupdown from 17.1.0.53 to 18.2.0.44
4. and after install and rebuilding project it gives me below errors.

```
Error       The Java type `mono.android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout_DrawerListenerImplementor` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted. HXSV1.Android           
Error       `mono.android.support.v4.content.Loader_OnLoadCanceledListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.Content.Loader+IOnLoadCanceledListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null    HXSV1.Android           
Error       `mono.android.support.v4.view.ViewPager_OnPageChangeListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager+IOnPageChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   HXSV1.Android           
Error       `mono.android.support.v4.view.AsyncLayoutInflater_OnInflateFinishedListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.View.AsyncLayoutInflater+IOnInflateFinishedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null HXSV1.Android           
Error       `mono.android.support.v4.content.Loader_OnLoadCompleteListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.Content.Loader+IOnLoadCompleteListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null    HXSV1.Android           
Error       `mono.android.support.v4.view.ViewPager_OnAdapterChangeListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager+IOnAdapterChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null HXSV1.Android           
Error       `mono.android.support.v4.view.ViewPager_OnPageChangeListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager+IOnPageChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null HXSV1.Android           
Error       The Java type `mono.android.support.v4.view.ViewPager_OnPageChangeListenerImplementor` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted.    HXSV1.Android           
Error       `mono.android.support.v4.view.AsyncLayoutInflater_OnInflateFinishedListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.View.AsyncLayoutInflater+IOnInflateFinishedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.AsyncLayoutInflater, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null HXSV1.Android           
Error       `mono.android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout_DrawerListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout+IDrawerListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null HXSV1.Android           
Error       The Java type `mono.android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout_PanelSlideListenerImplementor` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted.    HXSV1.Android           
Error       The Java type `mono.android.support.v4.content.Loader_OnLoadCanceledListenerImplementor` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted.  HXSV1.Android           
Error       `mono.android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout_DrawerListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout+IDrawerListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null    HXSV1.Android           
Error       The Java type `mono.android.support.v4.content.Loader_OnLoadCompleteListenerImplementor` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted.  HXSV1.Android           
Error       `mono.android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout_OnRefreshListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.Widget.SwipeRefreshLayout+IOnRefreshListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.SwipeRefreshLayout, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null    HXSV1.Android           
Error       `mono.android.support.v4.view.ViewPager_OnAdapterChangeListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager+IOnAdapterChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   HXSV1.Android           
Error       `mono.android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout_PanelSlideListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.Widget.SlidingPaneLayout+IPanelSlideListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   HXSV1.Android           
Error       `mono.android.support.v4.content.Loader_OnLoadCompleteListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.Content.Loader+IOnLoadCompleteListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null    HXSV1.Android           
Error       `mono.android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout_OnRefreshListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.Widget.SwipeRefreshLayout+IOnRefreshListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   HXSV1.Android           
Error       The Java type `mono.android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout_OnRefreshListenerImplementor` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted.    HXSV1.Android           
Error       `mono.android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout_PanelSlideListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.Widget.SlidingPaneLayout+IPanelSlideListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.SlidingPaneLayout, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null HXSV1.Android           
Error       The Java type `mono.android.support.v4.view.AsyncLayoutInflater_OnInflateFinishedListenerImplementor` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted. HXSV1.Android           
Error       `mono.android.support.v4.content.Loader_OnLoadCanceledListenerImplementor` generated by: Android.Support.V4.Content.Loader+IOnLoadCanceledListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null    HXSV1.Android           
Error       The Java type `mono.android.support.v4.view.ViewPager_OnAdapterChangeListenerImplementor` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted. HXSV1.Android
```

I want to update sfnumericupdown nuget because it have issue in step value up and down in Ukraine Language.
step value is 0.1 and Value is 46.2, now when i tap numeric up icon then value becomes 55/255/555, it means value not changing as per step value.

any help?
thank you.

Comment: Try to update your Xamarin.forms to the latest version.

Comment: Hey @JackHua-MSFT ,  Currently using xamarin forms v4.7 which is latest stable build and still having an issue

Answer (score 1):

Greetings from Syncfusion.

We have checked the reported issue with the provided steps in SfNumericUpDown control with a simple sample and control is working fine from our side. Could you please confirm whether all projects have the same Xamarin Forms version. Please have the sample and video for reference from the below link.

Sample Link: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Updown-1262080342

Video link: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/UpdownVideo364340833

Screenshot:

[UpDown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH083.png)

Please check with the sample and if the issue still persists please modify the same with the issue reproducing steps and also mention in which scenario you could reproduce the issue which will be helpful for us to analyse further and provide an appropriate solution.

Regards,
Sridevi S.